# QGIS 3.2 - number field display in attribute table in american format

Tags: attribute-table, qgis-3

Since upgrading to QGIS 3.2.0 the int and numeric formatted fields are displaying in the attribute table with a comma added for numbers of more than 3 digits (e.g. 12,345 instead of 12345).

It looks like I am in an American version and I assume it is just a setting but I have searched through the options/settings/properties and no success so far.

I have also reinstalled QGIS 3.2 to make sure I haven't ticked an American installation option but no change.

How can I 'switch off' that comma??

I previously run QGIS 2.18.13 and the number display in the attribute table was without the comma.

Answer (score 1):

after further research it seems to be a bug in the version 3.2.0. 
The issue doesn't appear in version 3.0.0, neither in version 3.2.1

That doesn't fix the problem for 3.2.0 but would be a workaround :-)

Cheers,
Claudia

Comment: Yes - the bug was fixed in 3.2.1, so the solution here is to upgrade to the patch release (which you should always do anyway!)